# How to set config variables for cloud functions using gcloud cli

Tags: firebase, configuration, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

My Firebase default service account ( xxxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com ) is deleted and cannot be recovered.
Hence I created different service account and now I have to deploy functions using gcloud CLI using 
 `gcloud beta functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --service-account=NEW_SERVICE_ACCOUNT` command.
How do I set firebase config variable using gcloud CLI which I can access via `functions.config()`.

Comment: WHat is this `functions.config()` command? From where the config is recovered?

Answer (score 0):

When you use Cloud Function, you can defined environment variable that you can use like this in Node

```
const val = process.env.KEY
```

To set this `KEY=val` into cloud function, you [can use the env vars setter parameter](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#setting_environment_variables)

For reusing the Firebase `functions.config()`, and by looking [the source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/master/src/config.ts#L55), it should work like this (I didn't test)

1. Define a JSON for your config, as [described in the retrieve part of the Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#set_environment_configuration_for_your_project)

```
{
  "someservice": {
    "key":"THE API KEY",
    "id":"THE CLIENT ID"
  }
}
```

2. Make it **inline** and store it into a [CLoud Functions file format](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#setting_environment_variables). The key of the environment variable must be `FIREBASE_CONFIG`. The result must be like this (name it `config.yaml` for example)

```
FIREBASE_CONFIG: '{"someservice":{"key":"THE API KEY","id":"THE CLIENT ID"}}'
```

3. Add the file env vars to the Cloud Function

```
gcloud functions deploy --env-vars-file=config.yaml ....
```

*Note: Why using a file?*

Great question, because you can also use the `--set-env-vars` param. 2 problems

1. First, you need to inline the content and to skip the double quote `"` character. For this, you can do `--set-env-vars=TEST=$(echo "'$(cat config.json | sed -z 's/\n//g')'")`
2. The first solution works **ONLY** if you haven't comma `,`. With comma, the gcloud command is lost and, even if you set your json inline content between simple quote `'`, it considers it as a new env var definition and fail.

Because I didn't have tested, I'm interested to know if this solution works or not!